# Checking out SVN trunk subfolder and overriding existing files

Tags: svn, drupal, version-control

My local file structure is set as follows:

drupal->sites->all->modules->custom

and drupal->sites->all->modules->custom2

Of course modules has tons of other submodules but I am only concerned with custom and custom2. I also have a SVN URL that has the following structure:

https:/someurl/trunk/drupal/

Under modules I ONLY have custom and custom2 and NO other submodules.

So the idea is to just have one checkout URL that can get those folders and contents and override my local versions of custom and custom2.

Sorry If I am not making sense but I need some serious help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you are looking for [Sparse Directories](http://www.subversion.org.cn/svnbook/nightly/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

Otherwise, you could create an [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) reference for each of custom and custom 2.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much hit the limit of Subversion in this case. Subversion was designed for easy of use and simplicity. You checkout a project and do your work. That works 90% of the time, but there are exceptions, and you've hit one of them.

If you want to use Subversion, there are two ways you can do this:

- **Use Branches**: Make a branch in the configuration you want, and use it. You'll have to keep merging and rebasing, but that's not all that difficult.
- **Use a *build* file to create the configuration you need**: In this case, you do your checkout, but you'd do a build using something like a `Makefile` or an Ant `build.xml` file to reconfigure the directory structure for you.

What you need is something that can allow you to *configure* the way you want the checkout to work. With these systems, you create a *view* that specifies what directories you checkout and where. [Perforce](http://perforce.com) and [ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/) comes to mind. I'd skip ClearCase. It's slow and takes massive amounts of hardware. Perforce is lighting fast and is cheaper. With Perforce, you define a *view* that tells Perforce what you want to checkout, and where you want it to appear in your working directory.

Perforce is free for small projects (2 users and five views) or for open source projects. I haven't been on a project that has used it for a while because it's just not worth the cost and complexity. However, in your case, it might fit your needs better than Subversion. You can download it for free and try it out.

Yes, you were asking how to do this in Subversion, but Subversion just might not do what you want as easily as other tools.